# Adding Images to SQLite Database Table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm a relative newcomer to Android and Java. I am having some trouble adding an image to my SQLite database table. Below is my table design:

```
private static final String CREATE_GALLERY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
    + GALLERY_TABLE + "("
    + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
    + IMAGE + " BLOB,"
    + TITLE + " TEXT,"
    + CAPTION + " TEXT" + ")";
```

This is my method to add an `image`, `title` and `caption` to the `gallery` table:

```
public boolean createGallery(byte[] image, String title, String caption) throws SQLiteException {
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

 values.put(IMAGE, image);
 values.put(TITLE, title);
 values.put(CAPTION, caption);

 long result = db.insert(GALLERY_TABLE, null, values);

 if (result == -1)
  return false;
 else
  return true;
}
```

Within my activity I have the following methods:

```
//user selects image from gallery
public void selectImage() {
 selectButton.setOnClickListener(
  new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
   }
  }
 );
}

//This method is called when user selected image from gallery
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
  Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
  viewImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
 }
}
public void uploadImage() {
 uploadButton.setOnClickListener(
  new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) viewImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

    boolean isInserted = myDb.createGallery(
     encodedImage.getBytes(),
     addTitle.getText().toString(),
     addCaption.getText().toString()
    );

    if (isInserted == true) {

     Toast.makeText(gallery.this, "Image uploaded successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else
     Toast.makeText(gallery.this, "Image upload has failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
  }
 );
}
```

I am able to select an image from the gallery and when selected I have an `ImageView` named `viewImage` which successfully shows the image I selected. I am also able to successfully insert to the database, the title and caption are inserted but the image column is blank. Any idea where I may have gone wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding a byte array, then turning that string back into a byte array?  Wouldn't you just want to put the compressed byte array in the db?  It'll be smaller and faster.  Also, check its size in the log and make sure it makes sense.

Comment: @DougStevenson I was following tutorial a guys tutorial on YouTube but he was sending to a server and not an SQLite Database so the end result was different, so I just tried to add the encodedImage to database. What should my code look like if I wanted to just add the compressed byte array to the db?...sorry, I'm really new to android programming.

Comment: Your compressed image bytes are in byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().

Comment: @DougStevenson So do I just remove `Base64.encodeToString` and `, Base64.DEFAULT`? So that it is `String encodedImage = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();`

Comment: You remove the entire line that does the Base64 encode and just store the results of the image compression.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry for being a total nuisance, but I am not entirely sure how to do that. It's probably something simple but I've kinda been thrown into the deep end with Java. Would you be able to post the code in an answer below?

Comment: No, because it wouldn't answer your question.  I simply had my own a question about your question that seemed odd to me.  I think you'll need to debug this by verifying all the values are what think they are, and then edit your question when you have specific details about things that aren't working the way you expect.